# Finite groups for which the element orders form an arithmetic progression

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Which are the finite groups $G$ such that the element orders of $G$ form an arithmetic progression? Several remarks:

1. $S_3$, $A_4$ and any $p$-group of exponent $p$ satisfy this property.
2. If $G$ satisfies this property and $p_1<p_2<...<p_k$ are the prime divisors of $n=\mid G\mid$, then $p_2=2p_1-1$, and consequently $(p_1,p_2)\in \{(2,3),(3,5),(7,13),(19,37),...\}$.
3. If $G$ satisfies this property and there is $a\in G$ such that $o(a)=\exp(G)$ (in particular, if $G$ is nilpotent), then $G$ is a $p$-group of exponent $p$.

My impression is that the non-nilpotent groups whose element orders form a progression are of order $2^\alpha3^\beta$ (and consequently are solvable), but I failed in proving this.

Comment: $A_7$ makes a pretty sweet example here.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: Yes. -- One can even go one further, i.e. to spectrum $\{1, \dots, 8\}$ -- but that's the maximum. -- I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, your impression is not correct. -- A counterexample is the group ${\rm S}_5$, whose elements have orders $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and $6$.

As to groups with *spectrum* (i.e. set of element orders) equal to $\{1, \dots, n\}$: the maximum here is 8, and for $n = 8$ the only such group is an extension of ${\rm PSL}(3,4)$ by a unitary automorphism -- see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119095/the-set-of-orders-of-elements-in-a-group/119099#119099).

Comment: Yes, you are right: my impression is not correct. Thanks for your interesting examples!

Comment: Is it necessary that the positive integers in the spectrum of such a group be of type 1,2,...,$n$?

Comment: @MariusTarnauceanu: If the spectrum is not of type $1,2,\dots,n$, then there is no element of order 2, hence there are no non-solvable examples in this case.

Comment: Thanks again! Could I hope to find a classification of solvable groups of odd order satisfying this property?

Comment: How do you prove the impossibility of spectrum $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}$ for $n > 8$?

Comment: @DavidLHarden: See the paper of Brandl / Wujie cited in the answer I referred to. -- Is there is anything unclear about that paper?

Comment: I'm not seeing the link.

Comment: @DavidLHarden: Written out, the link is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119095/the-set-of-orders-of-elements-in-a-group/119099#119099 -- are links not visibly distinguished from the rest of the text in your browser?

Comment: Links are visibly distinguished from other text. I'm not sure what happened. Thanks for the link, anyway.