# Groups with maximal density of the set of orders of elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Based on the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119095/the-set-of-orders-of-elements-in-a-group), I am wondering:
Let $n>8$ and $G$ a finite group for which all orders of its elements are contained in $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ (denote the set of all such groups by $\mathcal G_n$). How big can $\dfrac{|\mathcal O(G)|}{n}$ be as $n$ grows? Here $\mathcal O(G)$ denotes the set of all  orders of elements of $G$.

From the previous question, we know $f(n):=\max\limits_{G\in \mathcal G_n} \dfrac{|\mathcal O(G)|}{n}<1$ for $n>8$.

> - Is it clear that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$? If so, are there any estimates for the decay?
> - Are there specific values of $n>8$ for which "good" lower bounds are known, i.e. groups with a relatively high density of  $\mathcal O(G)$ ?